# how to get items in solution explorer in visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

When i Open Any Project in Visual Basic 2010 Express by Clicking on A File that has extension .sln, the project is opened but there is no items in solution explorer and i can't run the project

the following is the screenshot
[image]

thanks for help

Comment: please fix the link, can't find any screenshot from current link.

Comment: when i upload image there is error message about the limetation

Comment: try to upload in http://imgur.com/

Comment: try to load project directly from your project folder. .vbproj

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the unloaded project and click "Reload".

If this is consistent then you are closing your solutions incorrectly.  You do **not** want to use the Unload Project context menu item.  Use File + Close Solution instead.

Comment: i want the solution desplay a project items